# Gulp/BrowserSync HTML Injector with ASP.NET cshtml/razor view

Tags: asp.net, razor, gulp, browser-sync

I'm working within an ASP.NET MVC 4 project. I'd like to use browser-sync to inject changes to markup in our razor syntax views without reloading the page.

I'm using Gulp to automate these browser-sync tasks and the html-injector module (https://github.com/shakyshane/html-injector) to inject html changes.

My goal is:

1. Run ASP.NET project.
2. Run Gulp with browsersync task.
3. Navigate to view A.
4. Make a change in view A's cshtml file.
5. See the change in view A without a page reload.

Here is my gulp task:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
var htmlInjector = require("bs-html-injector");

gulp.task("browserSync", function() {
  browserSync.use(htmlInjector, {
    files: ['**/*.*html']
  });
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'localhost:1234',
    files: ['Styles*/**/*.css']
  });
});
```

I'm proxying to port port 1234 because the ASP.NET project runs there.

This configuration works perfectly for plane *.html files. The changes are made in-place with no page reload necessary.

However, for *.cshtml files, it still does a complete page reload every time.

Has anybody managed to make this work? Or is it an inherent ASP.NET/Razor thing that the view must be completely regenerated for every change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://shermandigital.com/blog/use-browsersync-with-visual-studio/ ?

Comment: Hi Alex, did you solve this?

Comment: Hi Marv, yes but unfortunately I no longer have access to the code and cannot recall much about the solution as it was highly-specific and a relatively long time ago.